# joomla и вредоносная переадресация

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, php

Добрый день, уважаемые профессионалы. У меня вопрос такой: у моего товарища есть сайт на joomla 1.5, вчера днем сайт стал работать не корректно. При попытке открыть любую страницу идет пере адресация на сторонний сайт, [msn.com](http://msn.com). Насколько я понял это произошло в результате кражи кодов доступа к ФТП. Я опираясь на свои скромные знания и сообразительность нашел все файлы .htaccess, которые как раз отвечают за переадресацию и удалил их (всего около 35 штук!). Попутно снес ряд зараженным вирусами файлов. В результате у меня остался 1 htaccess взятый из бэкаппа и гарантированно надежный. Но проблема не пропала. Отсюда у меня вопрос - что еще мне надо предпринять что бы вернуть сайту нормальное функционирование, какие еще файлы могут быть ответственны за перенаправление?

Comment: @SKYnetRTX, любая php может перенаправлять.

Comment: как вычислить?

Comment: @SKYnetRTX, Что вычислить? Линк в студию.

Comment: ссылку на сайт давайте, будем решать!

Comment: а ещё желательно доступ на фтп))))

Comment: intv-tv.com

Comment: @SKYnetRTX, ну вот вы поудаляли - теперь половину страниц не находит. Никакой переадресации не увидел

Comment: короче непонятно какой ответ ждет этот пассажир... а интерес к вопросу был!

Comment: там полностью переставить бэкап решили. Так что я на данный момент даже не знаю статуса сайта.

Comment: и как это вы не заметили переадресации. Через 3 секунды после захода на сайт переводило на msn.com

Comment: @SKYnetRTX, нет не переводило. А сейчас уже 403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день, всем кто принимал участие в обсуждении данного вопроса. Спасибо за Вашу поддержку. Проблему решил следующим способом:
1) Сайт был полностью выгружен на мою машину;
2) По пути мой нод сжег 4 зараженных php файла, 2 из которых были аж по 25 мб весом. (сайт похудел сразу на треть веса, уж не знаю что там было, но видимо что-то большое ... 25 мб...);
3) В ручную проверил файлы в корне и в папках 1 уровня вложенности. Удалил еще 1 файл, который по сути не являлся вирусом, а всего лишь порносайтом залитым в корень сайта.
4) Удалил все .htaccess - более 30 штук. Добавил .htaccess правильной конфигурации в корень сайта, (можно например взять из дистрибутива, но у меня он был от прошлой правки).
5) Удалил все файлы до последнего на хостинге.
6) Сменил коды доступа на фТП. По сути сайт начал работать нормально.
7) Залил файлы на сайт. Добавил модули защиты и некоторые настройки .htacess провел, которые теоретически помогут избежать взлома в будущем. Но это только по данным одной из инструкций в интернете. А их там уж очень много.
8) Сделал БЭКАП всего что сделал. Пускай лучше будет;)
Спасибо за внимание к моей проблеме. Все. Конец. Успехов Вам в борьбе с злодеями вирусами и пополняйте базу Хэшкода своими достижениями и проблемами.

Comment: @skynetrtx,убрали бы вообще доступ по фтп. это самый верный способ защититься от атак по фтп. Используйте уже ссх :)

Comment: я обычно вообще фаерволлом закрываю все порты, которые не должны светиться наружу и открываю к ним доступ только нужным ип)

Comment: @thunder, вариант хороший :)

Comment: я просто придерживаюсь мнения -- зачем светить на сервере порты, если для "мира" будет использоваться только, например, 80 порт, а остальные только админом, разрабом или вообще не будет использоваться? ;) чем меньше информации о софте сервера ты выдаешь в мир -- тем меньше шансов, что его сломают на уровне системы/багов софта :)